# Deleting / removing with Mongoose with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first attempt at deleting data in a MongoDB database. I'm loosely following this tutorial (just the delete part) to no avail, https://www.airpair.com/javascript/complete-expressjs-nodejs-mongodb-crud-skeleton. I just want to delete all the requested people who are in the requested country. All of my other requests work so I will just post the code that I know is not working, everything else is fine.

**EDIT**
 The error I get in the log is "404 Not Found". When testing w/ Postman the response I get is, "Cannot DELETE /deletepeople/USA/John"

```
app.delete('deletepeople/:country/:name', function(req, res) {
        var countryReq = req.params.country;
        var nameReq = req.params.name;
        peopleModel
            .find({"country":countryReq}, function(err, country) {
                country.find({"name": nameReq}, function (err, person) {
                        person.remove(function (err, person) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.status(500).send();
                            }
                            return res.status(200).send();
                        })
                })
            })
    });

});
```

Comment: I see a down-vote, it would help me to know why this is a bad question.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but it would be helpful to clarify what's not working about what you're doing and note what debugging you've done so far. Looking at your code, I would expect that you're getting exceptions when you run it.

Comment: Great, thank you that is more helpful than a down-vote.

Comment: It's likely that your `person` is actually within a sub-document of an array here, and this is not how you "remove" such a thing. You would make your question clearer by actually posting a sample document you expect to match, and what the result should look like after the operation. But this would seem to rather be an `.update()` operation with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) instead, as the best way to approach this.

Comment: I got it figured out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
country.find({"name": nameReq}, function (err, person) {
```

The above line is causing you an error, what are you searching in a returned document? Its just an document and not a collection.

You can use the `id()` method in embedded docs:

Look at the subdocuments [http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html]

Comment: I thought I was following a similar logic to the example in the tutorial. Anyways, I just want to provide a name and a country and delete the provided person (by name) from the provided country.